# I'm new to html and need help fixing this button code, I want to a button that opens 3 online tabs at once and having trouble

Tags: html, button

Now I'm not very experienced with html, and I want to prank my friend, I want a button that open "Buddy Holly" by Weezer, "Never Gonna Give You Up" by rick astly and the Josh Hutcherson whistle meme links all at the same time, here is the code I have so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Link Button</title>
</head>
<body>

    <!-- Button that links to a website -->
    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kjr7US2Z9aY">
    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ">
    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z3J_MCbwaJ0">
        <button>Go to Example Site</button>
    </a>

</body>
</html>
```

If I can get some assistance, it would be appreciated and if you have some notes to improve it, I would love to hear about it.

I wrote it and it only opened one of the three link.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an updated version of your HTML code with a JavaScript function that opens the specified links when the button is clicked.

Note that modern browsers may block pop-ups, so make sure your browser settings allow opening pop-ups from the site.

```
<button onclick="openLinks()">Go to Example Site</button>
  <script>
    function openLinks() {
        window.open("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kjr7US2Z9aY");
        window.open("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ");
        window.open("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z3J_MCbwaJ0");
    }
</script>
```